# PowerApps SP Custom Form - Display fields as currency

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, list-form, powerapps-forms

I have a SharePoint form - customized with PowerApps - that contains 6 currency fields from SharePoint.

The first 5 are meant for user input, and the 6th is for totaling the 5 fields' values.

For an example of my issue, here's what I have for my first currency field (Air Cost):

OnChange:

```
UpdateContext({varFormat: Self.Text});
Reset(Self)
```

Default:

```
If(
    !IsBlank(varFormat),
    Text(
        Value(varFormat),
        "$#,##0.00"
    ),
   Parent.Default
)
```

Datacard Update property:

```
Value(DataCardValue37.Text)
```

So what I need is for this field to convert to USD while the user enters information in the form.  It does this correctly, and after submission, displays correctly in SP.

When an Approver then opens that form, those fields are displaying correctly again in the form, BUT they can't be modified.  If an Approver changes the value of one of those fields, the formatting goes away, and it won't update that field in SharePoint.

I don't know why this is happening. Maybe I need to set my variable on the `OnStart` property?

It's causing an issue because these Cost fields are "estimated", so they will frequently need to change. How can I set these fields up so that this can work?

Thank you!

Comment: You can set the `varFormat` variable to the column value in `App.OnStart` or `Form.OnNew`, `Form.OnEdit`, etc. Or set `Default` property to: `If(
    !IsBlank(varFormat),
    Text(
        Value(varFormat),
        "$#,##0.00"
    ),
   Text(Parent.Default,"$#,##0.00")
)`. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh.  Based on my field's OnChange/Default property, how would I set that on the OnStart property?  I plugged in the Default property you suggested, but it still loses it's formatting when in Edit mode - and won't update in SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Set `OnChange` property of text input control to:

```
Set(varFormat, Self.Text);
Reset(Self);
```

Set `Default` property of text input control to (same as given by you):

```
If(
    !IsBlank(varFormat),
    Text(
        Value(varFormat),
        "$#,##0.00"
    ),
   Parent.Default
)
```

Set `OnView` property of `SharePointIntegration` control to:

```
ViewForm(SharePointForm1);
Set(varFormat, Text(SharePointIntegration.Selected.'Air Cost'));
```

Set `OnEdit` property of `SharePointIntegration` control to:

```
EditForm(SharePointForm1);
Set(varFormat, Text(SharePointIntegration.Selected.'Air Cost'));
```

Make sure to use the correct name of your column in the formula and publish your changes to SharePoint from Power Apps.

Comment: Thank you!  All set now